# how to interpret ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_NAMESPACE on getGroups?

Tags: sonos

I'm troubleshooting some errors from the Sonos API, where calls to `getGroups` result in HTTP 404. Here's a sample response:

```
{
  "errorCode": "ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_NAMESPACE",
  "reason": "Unexpected error"
}
```

And here's the corresponding request (with token and household_id redacted):
`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" "https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/households/<household_id>/groups"`

This error is happening repeatedly for this particular token, which otherwise appears correct and was used to retrieve the household_id used above.

For most users, the same code path and request yields HTTP 200 and a collection of players and groups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the exact same error for 2 users and I can't replicate it on my end.

The documentation says;

> When your app sends a namespace that is not recognized by the player,
> you’ll receive an ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_NAMESPACE error response. Note
> that namespaces are case-sensitive.
> For example, if you misspelled the namespace, the player responds with
> an ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_NAMESPACE in the global namespace:
>
> {   "errorCode": "ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_NAMESPACE" }

https://developer.sonos.com/reference/types/globalerror/

Like you, I have not spelled anything incorrectly and as its working correctly for the vast majority of users. Again, I can get households for these particular users but not groups.

I am at a complete loss but if I find out the reason I'll follow up.

Thanks, Paul